# Google crawl rate is climbing but still no indexing?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, googlebot, crawl-rate

This might belong on another stack site but idk. Soooo.... A year ago I started two sites that I didn't want indexed by Google or any other search engine since both sites were being developed based on the seo results of other clients.

I was blocking both sites with the "no index,no archive" metatag technique and blocking all with robots.txt

Previously both of the sites would index fine. Recently I removed the metatags from both sites. On a clean index, I submitted new sitemaps to Google Webmaster Tools.

Within a couple of days I watched the crawl rate for both start to climb. One says 6 pages indexed but nothing is showing up when i search Google index (site:http://www.fakewebsite.com). The same is happening for the other.

I don't understand whats happening! I admit it could be a panic attack caused by impatiently waiting for spiders. But because it's happening on both sites the same it's scaring me away from ever using noindex metatags of any kind... ever again. And really I hope someone has experience with this.

Could someone please:
1. Give ideas for a problem and solution?
2. Or just tell me it's normal and I'm impatient?

Comment: probably belongs on Webmasters.se

Comment: How recently did you remove the meta tags? If you could paste your meta tags here (remove anything that would identify what your site is, if you wish to have privacy) and we'll be more than happy to help you. Also, if you choose an answer for your other questions, it will increase the likelihood that people will answer your questions. Welcome to the community! :)

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
<link rel='alternate' type='application/rss+xml' title='ROR' href='ror.xml'/> 
<meta name='robots' content='all'/> 
<title></title> 
<meta name='description' content=''/> 
<meta name='keywords' content=''/> 
<meta name='geo.position' content=''/> 
<meta name='geo.region' content=''/> 
<meta name='geo.placename' content=''/> 
<meta name='copyright' content=''/> 
<meta name='author' content=''/> 
<meta name='designer' content=''/> 
<meta name='' content=''/> 
<meta name='google-site-verification' content=''/>

Comment: Sorry for crappy format. I tried to post in in the origianl question via edit but looks like it was stripped out. Thanks.

Comment: You have to use the code tool on your question since it's code. Your meta looks good, though. How long ago did you make the changes to your meta?

Comment: Also try searching for just your URL in Google search, without the www or the site: Just like mysite.com

Comment: tried searching as suggested in google search and got nothing. On one it came up as the search instead link which isn't a bad thing i guess. I made the change to the metatags about 4 days ago.

Comment: Oh, give it a bit more time then. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's normal and you're impatient. :-) The fact that it's being crawled is a good sign.

Comment: Thanks. I would assume so too. Just seems a bit odd that Webmaster tools says that there are pages indexed yet their not being included in search results. I'll be trying a little of that patients stuff and taking a look in a couple days. Hoping for the best.

Comment: Hi @paulmorriss and @Melanie, I just started another site two days ago and the shallow crawl indexed the site home page and became available in search results in under 48 hours. And did so with very minimal crawl rate. Yet the websites I mentioned before [link](http://www.creditrepairadvisors.net) being one of them, has an amazingly high (maybe human induced?) crawl rate, shows 28 pages indexed in web master tools but yet nothing in search results after a week. I don't know whether to be worried about reviewing terms of service or if the noindex tag was ok but noarchive caused side effects. :(

Comment: I think just because it's in the index doesn't mean they'll decide to display it. Maybe they are wary in case its a content farm or some other site they don't want to encourage.

Comment: Man that would be a disaster. The site is a legit service provider so should clear fine.

Answer (score 1):

Oh man... I found it! In wm-tools under removal request! **An old removal request (index page!) from a different/previous Google account!** How did I miss that! Thank you all for your patients with me. I feel a fool now... But... I hope this saves a headache or two down the road for somebody! :)